# Expand members of templated type on first expansion level of natvis visualiser

Tags: visual-studio-2013, natvis

The default visualiser for `shared_ptr` in VS2013 has this (many, many things trimmed out!):

```
<Type Name="CA::shared_ptr&lt;*&gt;">
  <Expand>
    <Item Condition="_Ptr != 0" Name="[ptr]">_Ptr</Item>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

This means that in the debugger you have to expand the `shared_ptr` then expand the `[ptr]` 'member' to see the pointed-to object's members. The hierarchy for a pointer to int would look like (ignoring raw views, allocators and deleters):

```
myIntPtr
  [ptr]
    42
```

I'd like to write a replacement which places all the pointed-to object's members one level up, to sit at the level in the hierarchy where `[ptr]` currently sits. This would instead look like:

```
myIntPtr
  42
```

Is there some syntax that will allow that? I should note, I'm looking for general syntax to support displaying all of a template parameter's members, rather than something that will only work with `shared_ptr` - `shared_ptr` is just a handy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what the "ExpandedItem" tag is good for. They even give an example that is similar to yours. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx#BKMK_ExpandedItem_expansion

Comment: Looks like you're right! I no longer have access to the code and natvis file this was about so can't test it in that context but the documentation does look spot-on! Thanks!

Comment: @BenHymers can you please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359355/extend-display-range-of-arrayitems-indexlistitems-using-natvis?noredirect=1#comment127858705_72359355).