# Extend display range of ArrayItems/IndexListItems using natvis

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, natvis

I am trying to visualize a memory content using [natvis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022) which is pointed by a pointer. I have also tried to declare the memory as a vector. But every time the problem I am facing is that, during debugging the visualizer can show only first `50 entry`.

I am giving here a very minimal example. Suppose, the `pointer_array` is a member of `Foo` class. In the driver file an `array` of size 5000 is created which is pointed by the array. I would like to observe the value of the array with the variable `pointer_array`. Also I have tried to understand how `natvis` reacts with `std::vector` and that's why as a member variable a vector (`foo_vec`) is also declared.

`foo.h:`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){}

        uint32_t *pointer_array;
        std::vector<uint32_t> foo_vec;
};
```

`main.cpp:`

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
# define ARRAY_SIZE 5000

int main()
{
    Foo obj_1;

    uint32_t foo_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        foo_array[i] = i*2;
    }
    obj_1.pointer_array = foo_array;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        obj_1.foo_vec.push_back(i*3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The following `natvis file` I have used.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="Foo">
        <DisplayString>Testing_Natvis</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>5000</Size>
            <ValuePointer>pointer_array</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>

        <!-- Tested with IndexListItems but failed to fetch all data, still only first 49 entry -->
        <!-- <IndexListItems>
          <Size>5000</Size>
          <ValueNode>pointer_array[$i]</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems> -->

          <!-- Same result as like as pointer_array. Only first 49 entry is appeared -->
          <!-- <IndexListItems>
            <Size>foo_vec.size()</Size>
            <ValueNode>foo_vec[$i]</ValueNode>
          </IndexListItems> -->

          <!-- <ArrayItems>
            <Size>foo_vec.size()</Size>
            <ValuePointer>&amp;foo_vec[0]</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems> -->
        </Expand>
    </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

In the `launch.json` I have added extra only the following two lines:

```xml
"visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/natvis_file/file.natvis",
"showDisplayString": true,
```

For better understanding I am giving here a screenshot of the output where in natvis file I have used `IndexListItems` and given size 80 to see value from index 0 to 79 but the displayed last value is from index 49.[image: error natvis output]

And the following is showing that I have given the `size` value 6 and natvis perfectly is showing value from index 0 to 5.[image: correct output of natvis from vscode]

Any workaround to achieve all entry of the memory using Natvis?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you always want to display 5000 elements? Or the number of elements that are in the array at this point? If the second, how do you know how many elements are in the array?

Comment: I want to display `5000` element. Not the `5000th` or `array[4999]` value. So stack of value I want to see . [Here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1859#issuecomment-344070785) I have found that `debugger` cannot display more than `1000` value but in my case `natvis` is showing only first 50 value(index 0 to 49).

Comment: @WernerHenze I have added the screenshot of the produced output by natvis. Also in the previous comment I have given your answer.

Comment: @WernerHenze if you kindly take a look in the issue would be very helpful for me. I have modified the question(2 screenshot is provided where you can see the problem I am facing. Also described the background) and answered your queries too. If you have anything else to know can ask me. I am at a dead-end regarding this.

Comment: Does it work for `std::vector`? If yes, have you compared the STL natvis file?

Comment: @WernerHenze no. In my `natvis` file you can see the last two entry for the `std::vector` (which are commented though here). Those can display only first `50 entry [index 0 to 49]`. 

```have you compared the STL natvis file``` --  I have checked that file and syntax is same as mine. Or, with this question you have told me to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- According to this [release](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/v1.12.2) the problem is solved although there is still bug of displaying more than 1000 value using `ArrayItems` node. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9801) to get more information.
- This display range limitation is gone if `IndexListItems` is used. Following snippet could be used to see more than 1000 element

```xml
<IndexListItems>
   <Size>5000</Size>
   <ValueNode>pointer_array[$i]</ValueNode>
</IndexListItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4843) the limitation to 50 is "by design" and there is no intention to change it.

Comment: Why [`IndexListItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_IndexListItems_expansion) is not working? Is it also stop it's iteration while `i` reaches to 50?

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/blob/f342bf345dbc5a896d767786b9fa9ef1ee641ead/src/MIDebugEngine/Natvis.Impl/Natvis.cs#L651), can you please confirm me whether I am right or wrong here?

Comment: Found `ExpandedItem` which can expand `stl container (tested on std::vector)` till the index 999 as there is maybe a limitation of `size`, found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76798) and [this](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1859)

Comment: can you kindly take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9377#issuecomment-1227699968)? It is saying that display range limitation is removed but still I can see only first/at a time 1000 entry.

Comment: @user10634362 New comments on the issue suggest that it works for `IndexListItems` but not for `ArrayItems`. For those a new issue was opened [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9801).

Comment: yes, seen it already.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [code](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/blob/f342bf345dbc5a896d767786b9fa9ef1ee641ead/src/MIDebugEngine/Natvis.Impl/Natvis.cs#L155) for this restriction. So, I can offer an idea of a solution - you can show a part of the container

```xml
<IndexListItems>
  <Size>foo_vec.size()</Size>
  <ValueNode>foo_vec[$i]</ValueNode>
</IndexListItems>
<IndexListItems>
  <Size>foo_vec.size()-50</Size>
  <ValueNode>foo_vec[$i+50]</ValueNode>
</IndexListItems>
...
<IndexListItems>
  <Size>foo_vec.size()-4950</Size>
  <ValueNode>foo_vec[$i+4950]</ValueNode>
</IndexListItems>
```

Comment: for `std::vector`(maybe for all `stl container`) one can use `ExpandItem` which displays from `index 0 to 999`. This range is also a limitation, see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76798) and [this](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1859)

Comment: The method you have given I have tried before and it is really cumbersome. If there is any `chunk` would organize that would be great. Idea is to find the chunk number using size of the container(`foo_vec.size()`) and the MAX data limit of a chunk(that is 50 by design). So, to represent my data I need `5000/50 = 100 chunk`. If `Natvis` can take this decision and organize the data in those chunks will be great. I have no idea whether this theme is already present or not.